# new then throw in C++ constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator, throw

If I do

```
Bat::Bat() : m_member_str(new std::string("Am I freed?"))
{
  throw std::runtime_error("oops");
}
```

Is the `new`ly allocated `std::string` freed? I was thinking it might be because the destructor is not called.

**I am not using a std::string**, but my own class, just showing it as an easy example.

Comment: Btw you would have to take care of copy constructor and assignment operator in this class.

Comment: @sharptooth this class already inherits from boost::noncopyable.

Comment: Why would you ever want a `std::string *` member as opposed to a `std::string` member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example is the classic use case for smart pointers. `Bat` is not fully constructed, so the destructor won't be called, but the destructor for `m_member_str` and all other fully constructed members will be. If you don't want an ugly block like `try { foo(); } catch (...) { delete m_member_str; }`, you'll have to get comfortable with RAII.

`std::auto_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr` will help you in C++03, or their equivalents in C++11. There is very little disadvantage in using them for owned member pointers.

Comment: Given `std::auto_ptr` is recommended, it's worth pointing out that it will remove any chance of value semantic behaviour from the default-generated copy constructor, such that the class won't be safe in STL containers.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Good point. I'd like to add that this is a feature, not a bug, with dynamically allocated member pointers: The rule of three will be compile-time checked.

Comment: @TonyDelroy What you say is confusing. What Tony is saying is the class should **not** be copyable. i.e. inherit from boost:noncopyable.

Answer (score 3):

Fully constructed objects have their destructor called.
Partially constructed objects do not.

In your case, your `Bat` object is partially constructed, because you threw an exception from its constructor. So `~Bat()` will *not* be called.

`m_member_str` however, *is* fully constructed, and so its destructor *will* be called.
However, it is impossible for us to see the type of that object.

If it is a `std::string*` then nothing will happen. It is a pointer, and destroying a pointer does not delete the memory it points to.

If it is some form of smart pointer, then its destructor will be called, and it will safely handle the memory you allocated.

In general, as long as your members are RAII objects and have a meaningful destructor, they will get cleaned up no matter what.

If the are not, as in this case, then you have to deal with the consequences yourself, possibly bny catching the exception, freeing the memory and then rethrowing.

Answer (score 1):

No, that object will be leaked unless you take care of it. The best way is to use a smart pointer for the member variable. The general rule is that fully-constructed objects are destroyed during stack unwinding and the same applies to `m_member_str` variable, but since it is a raw pointer the destructor will be trivial and won't touch the pointed-to object.

Comment: Well, first, you shouldn't throw exceptions from a constructor unless you have a good reason. Second, avoid storing raw pointers. If you just allocated memory, put it in a smart pointer and store *that*. Then it will get handled safely

Comment: @unixman83: "short of catching exceptions this cannot be handled well"?  The very same answer says: "The best way is to use a smart pointer for the member variable."....

Comment: @jalf: you shouldn't throw exceptions (or do anything else) from *anywhere* unless you have a good reason...! ;-P. Programming is about encoding what there's reason to do. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You've completely changed your question - invalidating my original answer! ;-P

> Is the string allocated with the new freed?

No

> I was thinking it might be only because the destructor is not called

Not relevant.  To get deallocation, you basically need to have a constructed object for which the destructor *will* be called, and in which the constructor performs deallocation (or you can use a try/catch block and do it all explicitly).

> so how can I free m_member_str, if it was a member pointer?

(Firstly, the best general approach is to make the member variable `m_member_str` a string rather than a pointer-to-string - then the string destructor will clean up.)

If you must have a pointer, use a smart pointer to capture the pointer such that the smart pointer's destructor destructs the pointed-to object *and* deallocates the memory.  This will be invokes as the failing constructor destroys already-constructed member variables during the exception handling.